# Showing the age number as red and bolded in JSX code

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, conditional-statements, font-size

I have a web page which has a button (Change age), which increases the value of person's age every time it is pressed. How could I make so that when it's value exceedes 10, the number is shown on red backround and and the number itself is shown as bolded? The number should be shown on red background and bolded where it reads below the Change and Change age buttons:

The age is:

I need to use some kind of conditional rendering in JSX with changeBackground function, but I am not sure how. Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component
{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);


        this.changeClicked = this.changeClicked.bind(this);


        this.state = {
            name : 'jerry',
            age : 10
        }
    }


    changeClicked()
    {
        this.setState({nimi : 'Anne'});
    }


    changeAge()
    {
        //this.setState({age : this.state.age + 1, name : 'Jacob'})
        this.setState((prevStatus) => ({age : prevStatus.age + 1}));
        console.log("Age is " + this.state.age);
        //this.setState({name : 'Maureen'})
    }


    changeBackground()
    {
        this.setState({backgroundColor: 'red'});
    }

    render()
    {
        const age = this.state.age;
        const color = 'white';



        return (
            <div>
                {
                <p style={{color : 'red'}}>name and age information</p>
                }
                <h3 style={{backgroundColor : color}}>Name is {this.state.name} and age = {age}</h3>
                <button onClick={this.changeClicked}>Change</button>
                <button onClick={() => this.changeAge()}>Change age</button>
                <p>Age is: {age}</p>
                <div>

      </div>
                <Info nimi={this.state.name} address="Europe" />
            </div>
        )
    }
}





export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create a CSS class to style the element when the conditions are met then apply the class on the condition gets matched.
For example:-

```
.age-exceed-10{
color:red;
font-weight:500;
}
```

then

```
<p className={`${this.state.age>10:"age-exceed-10":""}`}>Age is: {age}</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

i made [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-chandrasekhar-hki4f?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) for you on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-chandrasekhar-hki4f?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark).
you can simply copy and use it

just add a css class like this :

```
.red {background-color: red;}
```

and the code like this:

```
render() {
const age = this.state.age;
let classes = "";
classes += this.state.age > 10 ? "red" : "";

return (
  <div>
    {<p style={{ color: "red" }}>name and age information</p>}
    <h3 className={classes}>
      Name is {this.state.name} and age = {age}
    </h3>
    <button onClick={this.changeClicked}>Change</button>
    <button onClick={() => this.changeAge()}>Change age</button>
    <p>Age is: {age}</p>
  </div>
);
```

}

Comment: you can add any thing you want to your css class like font-weight and etc

Answer (score 1):

Try out this part of the code {this.state.colorbackground === true ?

```
 import React from 'react';

    class App extends React.Component
    {
        constructor(props)
        {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                name : 'jerry',
                age : 10,
                colorbackground: false
            }
        }


        changeClicked = () => {
          this.setState({nimi : 'Anne'});
        }

        changeAge = () => {
            this.setState((prevStatus) => ({age : prevStatus.age + 1}));
            console.log("Age is " + this.state.age);
            if(this.state.age >= 10) {
              this.setState({
                  colorbackground: true
              })
            }
        }

        render()
        {
            const age = this.state.age;
            const color = 'white';

            return (
                <div>
                    {
                    <p style={{color : 'red'}}>name and age information</p>
                    }
                    <h3 style={{backgroundColor : color}}>Name is {this.state.name} and age = {age}</h3>
                    <button onClick={this.changeClicked}>Change</button>
                    <button onClick={() => this.changeAge()}>Change age</button>
                   {this.state.colorbackgorunf === true ?
                 <div style={{color: 'blue', background: 'red'}}>Age is: <span style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{age}</span></div> :
                  <p>Age is: {age}</p> }
                    <div>
          </div>
                    <Info nimi={this.state.name} address="Europe" />
                </div>
            )
        }
    }

    export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
  <p>Age is: {age > 10 ? (<b style={{color : 'red'}}>{age}</b>):{age}}</p>
```